# Cast char list column to symbol

Tags: kdb

I have a table which has ~ 3 billion rows in hdb. One of the column is char list, I want to cast this column to symbol after loading the hdb. But memory quickly crosses over 300GB which I cannot afford. Can this be optimized in any way?

Comment: How are you currently casting it to symbol? Using dbmaint?

Comment: @terrylynch I will update the question. I am loading the hdb and then trying to do cast.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to cast to symbol in-memory (temporary) or cast to symbol on-disk (permanent)? If in-memory, you shouldn't try to cast to symbol for all dates, you can just cast to symbol as you select from it (with a date filter) or build a wrapper function to handle this. You need to analyse how repetitive the strings are though as every string you cast to symbol gets interned and consumes memory. If the strings are very unique (.e.g long) then you may end up creating too many interned symbols leading to your memory blowup.

If on-disk you should be using Kx's dbmaint utility - it has a specific example of casting from char list (string) to enumerated symbol.

https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.md#fncol

You have to be **very** careful though - again you need to analyse the string column to ensure that it is repetitive enough to warrant casting to symbol (adding as few new symbols to the sym file as possible). If the strings are very unique then you should **not** cast to symbol as you risk polluting the sym file with a lot of new symbols.

Ultimately the most efficient approach is to make the permanent on-disk change assuming the strings are repetitive (e.g. short)

Comment: I am loading table in-memory and filtering data for one particular date. Problem is that even for single day it has more than 3 billion row. The strings in the said column are changing very rapidly so if I try to make it symbol when saving, it will blow up the sym file which will lead to delay in loading hdb which will solve this problem but create other.

Comment: I see. Why do you want the in-memory column to be type symbol then? To speed up filtering? Is this column the first `where` filter after the date filter? (I'm assuming the table is date-partitioned)